# Javascript location doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php

Here is the code.

```
echo"<button class='buttonajax' onclick='javascript:location = try.php;'>Go Back</button>";
```

I tried to redirect to another page through this button but it does not perform any function.

Please tel me what is the problem in this code?

Comment: `location=try.php` is going to look for a JS object named `try` which has a `php` attribute. You want `location='try.php'`, which is a STRING

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the location you’re sending the user to in quotes because otherwise Javascript will try to interpret it as a variable name:

```
echo"<button class='buttonajax' onclick='javascript:location = \'try.php;\''>Go Back</button>";
```